# Possible function in NodeJS that works the same as send_from_directory() from Flask?

Tags: python, node.js, express, flask

In Flask, there is a function [send_](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.send_from_directory.html)*[from](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.send_from_directory.html)*[_directory()](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.send_from_directory.html). I am currently working on a project where I am trying to create a secure cloud storage system with emphasis on the encryption/decryption of files using RSA.

I am currently coding this project in NodeJS/Express. Is there a function or a library in NodeJS that can help me accomplish the same functionality as the send_from_directory() function linked above.

Currently I am just trying to break apart the file name and and file contents and sending them separately, and putting them together on the other side. This sounds very inefficient and stupid in my head as surely there should be some other way to make this easier.

Comment: If by "send", you mean to send a file as a response to an http request, then you can use `res.sendFile()` (doc [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile)) from the Express mini-framework.  You construct your own full path by just combining the directory and path with `path.join()` rather than providing a directory and filename separately.

Comment: If you're trying to expose a whole directory of static files somewhat automatically so when the user requests a file by filename, then a matching filename from a target directory is automatically sent,  you can use `express.static()` (doc [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)) to expose a whole directory of static files at once.

Comment: @jfriend00 cheers mate, thanks for the tip. ill have a look! now that I actually think about it, I'm not too sure I can use them even though it's prob what I was looking for. I think I do have to split up the filename and file contents anyways because the file is encrypted in the server and needs to be decrypted before sending it back.

Comment: Yep, if you have to decrypt first, you're probably going to want to write your own code that reads the file as a stream, decrypts using a stream transform and then pipes to the response.